# My white device has turned yellow

Tags: cleaning, kitchen-safety

Here is my white device, which has turned yellow on one side while cooking an over done cheese burger:

[image: device color turned yellow]

Does anybody know whether it is possible to turn it back to the white color?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably not, plus it will get worse over time.

I've an old George Foreman with similar marking.
Neither oxygen nor chlorine bleach works - plus it smells.
The only thing that very slightly works is a good hard scrub with something quite aggressive, oven cleaner or barman's friend etc, which will eventually take all the paint off.

You'll just have to live with it.

Comment: Likely it's oxidized and polymerized oils, like furniture varnish. Might instead be the plastic itself (or plasticizer) getting oxidized. Barring a good hard scrub, or sandpaper, you have to live with it.

Comment: By oxygen, I assume you mean something like retrobrite - that's meant for a super specific kinda yellowing. If it was yellow all over, it might work, something about promine

Comment: Oxygen bleach == hydrogen peroxide. I had to google retrobrite; it's not as specific as that, it's just a kitchen spray cleaner with peroxide instead of chorine. Better for the environment as it breaks down to water & oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Try Magic Eraser Sponges, available at most stores that sell cleaning supplies. They really ARE magic for things like this very often! Worth the effort.

[https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Durable-Cleaning-Durafoam-Packaging/dp/B00BR1FSU8/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00BR1FSU8)